# iframes render blank in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, video, iframe, embed

I am trying to embed the following code into an MVC view:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="512" height="288" src="http://video-api.wsj.com/api-video/player/iframe.html?guid=BAB3CB48-960F-495C-89A1-8AC7B0C6F637"></iframe>
```

If I test it at http://www.csgnetwork.com/htmlcodetest.html, it works with no problem but if I put the same exact line into the source code of my view and then call it, it is just a blank page.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: yea, this happens with all browsers.  An example page is https://www.clipchan.com/home/about.  If you look at the source, you will see an <iframe>.  That video is not showing for any browser.  If I put a Youtube video in that same iframe, it works great.

Comment: Ok, I solved my own problem ... I'm an idiot.  Besides that, though, I was trying to load http content into an iframe that was hosted on a https page.